# $z(t) \mapsto \mathbb R$ or $z(t) \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Which notation is correct?

Tags: notation

> Let z(t) be a continuous function defined on $t_0 \leq t \leq t_1$
>
> Which of the notations is correct? $z(t) \mapsto \mathbb R$ or $z(t) \rightarrow \mathbb R$

Comment: That notation is not only incorrect, but it makes no sense. You're not mapping $z(t)$ to anything; the function assigns to each $t$ in the domain a unique $z(t)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is correct.

The function is $z: [t_0, t_1] \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $t \mapsto z(t)$.

Concretely: an example is $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $t \mapsto t^2$.

In general, the notation is "function name": "function domain" $\to$ "function codomain".

Then "function name": "input value" $\mapsto$ "output value".

Comment: Nice. I am curious what is the advantage of writing $t \mapsto t^2$ over $f(t)=t^2$ ? or does not make a difference?

Comment: @kaka The advantage of the former is that you don’t need to give a name for the function. If you want to name the function, there it doesn’t difference.

Answer (score 5):

You should write $z:[t_0, t_1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write $[t_0,t_1]\ni t\mapsto z(t)\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

$z(t\in[t_0;t_1])\in\mathbb{R}$
and to figure out that it's continuous, $z \in C^0(\mathbb{T})$, where $T=[t_0;t_1]$. If u want to use arrow it should be Dom(z) on left side.